projecting the climatic niche of a species onto PCA space, when visualizing, encountering empty plot is displayed."
Question:
I am trying to visualize species' niche suitability in R using ggplot2 after performing kernel density estimation (KDE) and resampling raster data. (I'm following the code from another PhD's paper as a reference, but I've hit an ob)
However, I keep encountering an issue where the plot comes out empty. I suspect this might be related to the plot limits (xlim, ylim), or it might be an issue with the data processing steps, particularly resampling the raster data or the coordinate system.
The data loading, PCA computation, and raster resampling steps seem to work without errors, but the visualization consistently results in a blank plot.
Below is the full code that I've been working with, followed by some questions I have about possible sources of the problem:
### Maria Angeles Perez-Navarro
### CREAF  10/2020
### multivariate niche characterization 
#*************************************#
rm(list = ls())
source('./niche_required_functions.R')

library(raster) 
library(dismo) 
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(ade4)
library(stringr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ks)
library(readr)[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/oTBvoKYA.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/oTBvoKYA.png)
library(ggplot2)

source('./niche_required_functions.R')
setwd("D:/maria_jiyeon")

# 1. Load clean occurrences and climate -------------------------------
table_sp_gbif  <- read_delim("total_interannual_chelsa_jiyeon.csv", delim=",", col_names=T)

# 2. Run PCA to create a common climatic space ----------------------------
table_sp_clean <- table_sp_gbif %>% dplyr::select(c(5:9)) %>% na.omit() 
table_sp_clean <- table_sp_clean %>% dplyr::select(bio1, bio5, bio6, bio12, bio17) %>% na.omit()

dudi_sp <- dudi.pca(table_sp_clean, scale = TRUE, scannf = FALSE, nf = 2)
str(dudi_sp)

summary(dudi_sp)
screeplot(dudi_sp)
factoextra::fviz_pca_var(dudi_sp, col.var = "contrib", gradient.cols=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FF0000"))

table_sp_field <- read_excel("total_or_jiyeon_cleaning_s_add.xlsx")
table_sp_pca <- suprow(dudi_sp, table_sp_field[, c(7:11)])$li
total_sp_li <- cbind(table_sp_field%>% dplyr::select(1,2,3,6), table_sp_pca[, c(1,2)]) # joining species and PCA
colnames(total_sp_li)[1] <- c("species")
total_sp_li <- total_sp_li[order(total_sp_li$species),]

# 3. Species niche characterization ---------------------------------------
x <- raster(ncol=2000, nrow=2000, xmn=-20, xmx=20, ymn=-20, ymx=20)
values(x) <- 0

sp_list <- table_sp_field$species %>% as.factor() %>% sort() %>% unique()

for (i in 1:length(sp_list)){
  work_specie <- total_sp_li[total_sp_li$species == sp_list[i], c(5,6)]
  hpi_sp <- Hscv (x=as.matrix(work_specie), binned=T, pilot="samse")
  niche_volume <- kde(x=work_specie, H=hpi_sp, compute.cont=T )
  
  xlim_values <- range(total_sp_li$Axis1, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)
  ylim_values <- range(total_sp_li$Axis2, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)

  plot(niche_volume, display="filled.contour2", drawpoints=F, cont=c(5,10,25,50,75,90,95),
       col = colorRampPalette(c("white", "orange"))(8), xlab="PCA1", ylab="PCA2", 
       xlim = xlim_values, ylim = ylim_values, main = paste0(sp_list[i]))

  ## Rasterize niche
  niche_rast <- raster(niche_volume)
  niche_rast@data@values[which(niche_rast@data@values < niche_volume$cont[95])] <- 0
  niche_suit <- niche_rast / max(values(niche_rast))

  ## Resample to match raster x
  res(x) <- res(niche_suit)
  a <- resample(niche_suit, x)
  a@data@values[which(is.na(a@data@values))] <- 0
  
  # Convert to dataframe for ggplot visualization
  niche_suit_spdf <- as(a, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
  niche_suit_df <- data.frame(niche_suit_spdf)

  ## ggplot visualization
  nicheplot <- ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data=niche_suit_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myblue) +
    geom_contour(data=niche_suit_df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = layer), colour = "grey45", breaks = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.75), linetype = "longdash", size = 0.22, alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_contour(data=niche_suit_df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = layer), colour = "black", breaks = c(0.90, 0.95), linetype = "longdash", size = 0.22, alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_point(aes(x = centroid$X1, y = centroid$X2), size = 0.3, col = "grey40") +
    geom_point(aes(x = mode$x, y = mode$y), size = 0.3, col = "black") +
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    ylim(-10, 10) +  
    ggtitle(sp_list[i]) +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab(expression("Environmental Axis 2 (26.7%)")) +
    xlab(expression("Environmental Axis 1 (48.2%)")) +
    labs(fill = "Suitability") +
    theme(legend.background = element_blank(), legend.title = element_text(size = 8), legend.text = element_text(size = 7), legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "lines"), axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 7), axis.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 9), plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 12, face = "bold", family = "serif", hjust = 0.5), text = element_text(family = "serif"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank())
  
  print(nicheplot)
}`

`
     
Questions/Details:

Plot Limits (xlim/ylim):
In the visualization part, I've manually set the plot limits using xlim(-10, 10) and ylim(-10, 10), but I suspect that this might not be aligned with the data in niche_suit_df. I’m not sure if these limits are inadvertently cutting off all data points, leaving the plot empty. Could these hard-coded limits be causing the issue? How can I dynamically set limits that reflect the data range properly?

Raster Resampling:
I’ve resampled the niche suitability raster (niche_suit) to match another raster (x) to ensure consistent resolution and extent. While the resampling process doesn't throw an error, I'm concerned that something might be going wrong here and leading to issues during plotting. The resolution and extent appear to match when I check them, but the plot remains blank.

Niche Suitability Data:
The data in the niche_suit_df seems valid when I inspect it, and the raster's extent and values look reasonable after resampling. However, I wonder if something subtle is going wrong when the data is converted into a SpatialPixelsDataFrame or data.frame. Is there a potential issue with how I’m converting the raster to a format suitable for ggplot2?

Would appreciate any insights into why the plot might be rendering as empty and how I can

